# Show $x^k \equiv a\space(mod\space p)$ has at most one solution when $k$ and $p-1$ are coprime

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $p$ be a prime, and $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $hcf(k, p-1) = 1$. If $a$ is an integer then show that $x^k \equiv a \space\text{mod}\space p$
has at most one solution.

So far i've tried assuming that $x$ and $y$ are two distinct solutions, so $x^k \equiv y^k \space\text{mod}\space p$, and therefore $x^k - y^k\equiv 0\space\text{mod}\space p$.

I know that   $$x^k - y^k = (x-y)\sum_{i=0}^{k}{x^{k-i}y^{i}}$$
So $x^k - y^k = (x-y)(\sum_{i=0}^{k}{x^{k-i}y^{i}})\space\text{mod}\space p$, but I'm not sure how to show that $x=y$ is the only solution to this.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Fermat's little theorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$nk+l(p-1)=1$, $x^k=y^k$ implies $x=x^{nk+l(p-1)}=$

$={(x^k)}^nx^{l(p-1)}=y^ky^{(l(p-1)}=y$ since $x^{p-1}=y^{p-1}=1$ from little fermat, thus $x\rightarrow x^k$ is injective.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Discrete Logarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteLogarithm.html),

$k\cdot$ind$_gx\equiv$ind$_ga\pmod{p-1}$

Now using [Solution of Linear Congruence](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Solution_of_Linear_Congruence), there will be exactly $(k,p-1)=1$ solution if $(k,p-1)$ divides ind$_ga$